# Delete in a BST

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

I was wondering why my delete method for my BST is not working. I have implemented recursion and for someone reason, no nodes are being deleted.

```
def delete(self,node, val):
    if(node == None):
        return None
    if(val < node.data):
        node.left =  self.delete(node.left,val)
    elif( val > node.data):
        node.right = self.delete(node.right,val)
    else:
        if(node.right ==None and node.left ==None):
            return None

        elif(node.left==None): # delete the node holding 1 child
            node=node.right

            return node

        elif(node.right==None):
            node = node.left
            return node
        elif(node.right and node.left):
            delete = node.right
            while(delete.left):
                delete = delete.left
            node.data = delete.data
            node.right = delete(node.right,delete.data)
    return node


    testTree.delete(testTree.root,30)
    testTree.printInorder(testTree.root)
```

Could it be I'm not deleting directly?

Comment: When you are deleting, you have to work at the immediate parent level to update the pointer to the node you are deleting. So, although you are busy deleting a node, the pointer to it remains active in its parent.

Comment: `node` is a local reference.  Changing what it points to won't change your data structure.

Answer (score 0):

You have written `node = node.right` but what you really want is `return node.right` (and similarly for the left case).

Because the parent's left or right child will then be set to the returned value, there should be no more references to the current node and it will be garbage collected.

Similarly, when `node` has no children, you are doing `del(node)` (by the way the parentheses are unnecessary) which just makes `node` an undefined name.
You should instead do `return None` so that the parent's left or right child will be set to `None`, and then the node will be garbage collected from having no references.

In the case where the node to be deleted has two children, you are setting `node.data = delete.left` which is presumably assigning a node to something that should be integer valued. You probably want `node.data = delete.data`.

Furthermore, you probably don't want to just do `del(node.right)`. All this will do is remove the attribute `right` from `node`. You should keep track of `delete`'s parent and remove it as a child of that parent.

Another issue is if `delete` has children. All said, there are a number of issues, so it could be any one of these.

Edit: To address the most recent version of the code, the two children case may be done something like this:

```
swap_node = node.right
parent = node

# Find the leftmost child of the right subtree and its parent
while swap_node.left:
    parent = swap_node
    swap_node = swap_node.left

node.data = swap_node.data
# The next line works whether or not swap_node has a right child
parent.left = swap_node.right
return node
```

This moves the data from the leftmost child of the right subtree to the current node, and deletes that node from its tree. You don't need a recursive call to delete because you already know where the node is and that it has no left child.

Comment: As I said there are a large number of problems so please post the updated code.

Comment: I have added an edit to my comment to address the case of two children. Also one thing I didn't notice originally is that you have a local variable with the same name as the function it is inside, so I renamed that variable from `delete` to `swap_node`